# .NET doesn't recognize namespace from newly installed GAC assembly?

Tags: .net, gac, winscp, winscp-net

I installed WinSCP (dll) to GAC, as directed https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#gac.

But then when i had `using WinSCP;`, .NET couldn't build. i was able to navigate to the .dll in the GAC folder and add it directly. But why didn't VS pick up the newly assembly after it was added to GAC?

in response to comments below, the reference XML of this reference (after adding it explicitly) is:

```
<Reference Include="WinSCPnet, Version=1.3.7.7601, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2271ec4a3c56d0bf, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WinSCPnet\1.3.7.7601__2271ec4a3c56d0bf\WinSCPnet.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: I can't find it when I try

Comment: @T.S. - I can browse to the .dll to add the reference, but I thin that I don't want an absolute path to a dll in the GAC?

Comment: it's not there. if i browse I can find the dll

Comment: You can try this. right click on project - unload. Then - edit. Go to where other references are and manually add xml with your assembly name. then do reload and try do `using`. See if this works. If not - you just didn't register correctly

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what you mean be 'Go to' where other references are?

Comment: Once you loaded your project XML in text editor there is reference section. In fact, you can add it via Browse then unload project and modify it, so it looks similar to this (remove path, etc) `<Reference Include="Infragistics35.Web.v8.3, Version=8.3.20083.1009, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />`

Comment: Thanks. I've got that. it also looks exactly like that, does this mean that it's looking at GAC in general and not the specific path of this DLL? I also have a <HintPath> tag that I would imagine doesn't have to be correct on the deploy server (I open the project on production and build it there)

Comment: Whole point here is to remove `HintPath` and other noise and leave only one XML `Reference` line. And see if that works. `HintPath` is for, when DLL is not in GAC, it will look into this path.

Comment: it works. thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why can't you see it in *Add Reference - Assemblies -- Extensions*

After adding via browse you've got this

```xml
<Reference Include="WinSCPnet, Version=1.3.7.7601, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2271ec4a3c56d0bf, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WinSCPnet\1.3.7.7601__2271ec4a3c56d0bf\WinSCPnet.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Unload project and edit xml to

```
<Reference Include="WinSCPnet, Version=1.3.7.7601, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2271ec4a3c56d0bf, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

Save and reload. If this doesn't work, registration in GAC went bad

Comment: I haven't restarted my pc or VS since installing to GAC? no. it's defintely not there